# Open Gmail app from my app

Tags: ios, uiapplication

I'm trying to send an email from my app. But what I want is if user is having Gmail app on his/her phone, then mail should be sent using it. If Gmail app is unavailable then the user should be redirected to Mailbox.

So how can I know if user contains Gmail app and how can I redirect user to it.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19281934/2500457 will help

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a URL handler for Gmail for iOS to compose a message?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19281933/is-there-a-url-handler-for-gmail-for-ios-to-compose-a-message)

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You need to use custom URL Scheme. For gmail application its:

```
googlegmail://
```

If you want to compose a message there you can add more parameters to this URL:

```
co?subject=Example&body=ExampleBody
```

You can determinate if any kind of application is installed using this code (just replace customURL obviously for an other apps):

```
NSString *customURL = @"googlegmail://";

if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] 
canOpenURL:[NSURL URLWithString:customURL]])
{
  [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:customURL]];
}
else
{
  //not installed, show popup for a user or an error
}
```

Comment: Can you define a way to attach image?

Comment: It's working very fine but what if I want to add the parameter of "To:" means how can I add email id whom I want to send mail like you add subject and body?

Comment: @YuvrajSinh you can add it like this:  `"googlegmail:///co?to=support@test.com&subject=Hello&body=Hi"`

Comment: `googlegmail:///co?` and `googlegmail://co?`, both are working on iOS 12.1.2 + Gmail 5.0.190113

Answer (score 42):

## Setup for iOS9+

As explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/419119/launch-an-app-from-within-another-iphone), **if you're on iOS9+**, don't forget to add `googlegmail` to `LSApplicationQueriesSchemes` on your `info.plist`

[image: my info.plist]

## Code to open GMail

Then, you can do the same as the accepted answer (below is my swift 2.3 version):

```
let googleUrlString = "googlegmail:///co?subject=Hello&body=Hi"
if let googleUrl = NSURL(string: googleUrlString) {
    // show alert to choose app
    if UIApplication.sharedApplication().canOpenURL(googleUrl) {
        if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
          UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(googleUrl, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
        } else {
          UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(googleUrl)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: iOS 11: it works w/o adding scheme to your own app. Also you can add `to` argument: `"googlegmail:///co?to=support@test.com&subject=Hello&body=Hi"`

Comment: @silvansky, do you know how to pass multiple lines body? I mean, including new line? So, instead of "Hi" it is "Hi!" then "Bye" on the new line.

Comment: How to add a space in body?

Comment: Have you tried usin `%20` (for space) and `%0D%0A` (for new line) ... it would be something like this: `googlegmail:///co?to=support@test.com&subject=Hello&body=Text%20before%20new%20line.%0D%0AText%20after%20new%20line.` ... check this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15019689/html-insert-line-break-in-email-subject-like-20-is-a-space

Comment: For the `canOpenURL` to work I needed to add `googlegmail` to plist. On iOS 10+.

Comment: `googlegmail:///co?` and `googlegmail://co?`, both are working on iOS 12.1.2 + Gmail 5.0.190113.

Comment: Source code for the Info.plist `<key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
 <array>
  <string>googlegmail</string>
 </array>`.

Comment: How do I add a zip file as an attachment?

Answer (score 4):

For **Swift 3.0+**

Notes:

1. This solution shows how to use spaces or newlines in the arguments to the URL (Gmail may not respect the newlines).
2. It is NOT necessary to register with LSApplicationQueriesSchemes as long as you don't call canOpenURL(url).  Just try and use the completion handler to determine if it succeeded.

   ```
   let googleUrlString = "googlegmail:///co?to=\(address.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .alphanumerics) ?? "")&subject=\(subject.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .alphanumerics) ?? "")&body=\(buildInfo.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .alphanumerics) ?? "")"

   if let googleUrl = URL(string: googleUrlString) {
       UIApplication.shared.open(googleUrl, options: [:]) {
           success in
           if !success {
                // Notify user or handle failure as appropriate
           }
       }
   }
   else {
       print("Could not get URL from string")
   }
   ```

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't figure out why this wasn't working for me until I realised I was targetting a info_development.plist instead of the production-file info.plist

If you're like me and happen to have multiple Plists (one for development, one for prod etc) make sure you edit it everywhere. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

****Swift 5****

These answers can open gmail but what if the user do not have gmail installed in the device? In that case I have handled opening apple mail/outlook/yahoo/spark. If none of them are present, I am showing an alert.

```
@IBAction func openmailAction() {
    if let googleUrl = NSURL(string: "googlegmail://") {
        openMail(googleUrl)
    } else if let mailURL = NSURL(string: "message://") {
        openMail(mailURL)
    } else if let outlookURL = NSURL(string: "ms-outlook://") {
        openMail(outlookURL)
    } else if let yahooURL = NSURL(string: "ymail://") {
        openMail(yahooURL)
    } else if let sparkUrl = NSURL(string: "readdle-spark://") {
        openMail(sparkUrl)
    } else {
        // showAlert
    }
}

func openMail(_ url: NSURL) {
    if UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(url as URL) {
        UIApplication.shared.open(url as URL, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
    }
}
```

You might also may have to add this in the plist

```
<key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
<array>
    <string>googlegmail</string>
    <string>ms-outlook</string>
    <string>readdle-spark</string>
    <string>ymail</string>
</array>
```

Comment: Can one also include an attachment as well?